# Android Crop Intent

Tags: android, camera, crop

I just have a question. Is there any reason why I shouldn't use this Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
```

in order to crop the image I just took. I understood that some devices don't support this, and it seem to be more of a hack than a solution because it is not documented at all. Please provide some strong arguments pro/con.

Answer (score 0):

Like you say, this action is not supported on all devices, so you should check for ActivityNotFoundException when you start the activity, find an alternative way to crop on those devices or ask the user to install an app for that such as QuickPic.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, android-sdk doesn't provide you such Intents.
Check Mr Murphy's answer: http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html

The newer versions of eclipse itself is not supporting this and is showing errors.
I strongly recommend you not to go with this intent, instead write some yourself or use some third party libraries.